# i want to get distance between two geo points in android

Tags: android

hi friends
i want to get distance between two geo points.
but here i get one problem in this my application .
when i entered one geo point of sea location and one of any city so i get response in kml file nodata in kml file...
i want to use google map to find find out distance between two cities..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated above, the Location Class is the way to go. Here is the code I have used :

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");  

locationA.setLatitude(pointA.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);  
locationA.setLongitude(pointB.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  

Location locationB = new Location("point B");  

locationB.setLatitude(pointB.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);  
locationB.setLongitude(pointB.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  

double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

In this example, both pointA and pointB are instances of the GeoPoint class.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Look for `distanceBetween` or `distanceTo` methods